# Circular module dependencies between stores

Tags: react-native, flux, reactjs-flux

In my react native app that tracks instrument practice I have three stores:

- SessionStore
- GoalStore
- InstrumentStore

The stores each manage one model (Session, Goal, Instrument) and getting/updating the server via a REST api.

The SessionStore listens to actions regarding Sessions (obviously): session.add, session.update. But it also listens to changes to the other stores, to be able to update the Sessions if a Goal or Instrument changes name.

Correspondingly the InstrumentStore listens to Instrument actions, but also to Session actions to update statistics on how many sessions uses a particular instrument.

To be able to not have race conditions, the InstrumentStore will act on the action session.add but wait for the SessionStore to handle the action first (to ensure the Session has been updated in the API). To do this I use dispatcher.waitFor with the SessionStore dispatchToken as a semaphore.

The problem: since all stores use each others dispatchTokens they all have to import each other. This is a circular dependency on modules and leads to strange race conditions. Sometimes one of the stores haven't been constructed when it's included by one of the other stores.

Here are my stores: https://github.com/osirisguitar/GuitarJournalApp/tree/feature/flat-ui/js/stores

Am I using the flux pattern the wrong way?

**Addition**

This is what I want to happen (in sequence):

Session is updated:

1. Send updated session to API
2. Refresh SessionStore
3. Refresh GoalStore
4. Refresh InstrumentStore

2, 3 and 4 need to wait for 1 to complete, that's why GoalStore and InstrumentStore need the SessionStore dispatch token.

Goal is update:

1. Send updated goal to API
2. Refresh GoalStore
3. Refresh SessionStore

2 and 3 need to wait for 1, this is why SessionStore needs the GoalStore dispatchToken which introduces the circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You have some duplication going on.

All stores will hear all dispatches.  That's the beauty of having a single dispatcher.  So when you dispatch a `sessions.add` or `sessions.update` action, you're hitting three different Stores, and two of them are doing the exact same thing.  That's a no-no.

As a rule, each Store's dispatch token should only be responsible for updating **that** store.  So your Goal and Instrument stores should *not* be updating the SessionsStore.  The `.refresh` and `.emit` should be happening within the SessionsStore dispatch token only.

---

EDIT to answer your edited question.

I think your confusion is because you're not recognizing that the `dispatcher.register` takes in a *function* as it's argument, and not an object.

Functions, in JS, do not evaluate their contents on declaration.  They are evaluated when executed only.

Simple example;

```
func = function(){ console.log(testVar) } // No error, even though testVar is undefined
func() // ERROR: testVar is undefined
var testVar = 'hey';
func() // log: 'hey';
```

`dispatcher.register` takes a function as it's input, and returns an key (in the format `ID_#`).  That key is generated by the dispatcher itself *without running the input function*.  The input function is simply stored for later and run each time a payload is dispatched.

That means that you don't need the internal variables to be defined until your first dispatch.  And because you *also* don't want to dispatch anything until you've created your stores, this becomes a non-issue.

But it also means that the dispatcher, by default, has a sort-of circular dependency against itself (relying on the return values of it's own functions, as stored in external variables).  But that's the design of the dispatcher.  Unless you're going to write a new dispatcher, that's just part of the deal.

It's also worth pointing out that if you create a true circular dependency by calling multiple `waitFor`s that deadlock against one another, the dispatcher will correctly throw an error saying as much;

```
Dispatcher.waitFor(...): Circular dependency detected while waiting for ID_#
```

Comment: You're right, the GoalStore isn't supposed to say SessionStore.refresh() (and emitchange), it's supposed to say GoalStore.refresh(). But I still need the SessionStore dispatchToken to be able to wait for the SessionStore to finish its update before GoalStore can refresh...

I'll update the original question with the flow to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, that is very true - bit of a rookie javascript mistake there (didn't realize I was assigning a function). I think using getDispatchToken() in the dispatch instead of trying to obtain it at declaration time will solve it - thanks!

Comment: Actually, I take that back. dispatcher.register DOES return the dispatchToken (https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html). So what i did is implement my own getDispatchToken instead of using the one from flux utils. Anyway, thanks for sort of getting me on the right path :-)

Comment: Oh, sorry if my answer was confusing!  I used the term "key" instead of "Dispatch Token".  But in any case, glad you sorted it out.

Comment: NP, thanks again! (I realize my question is a bit confusing as well, but the goal of getting it working is met! :-) )